# Only round max or min of y-axis in nvd3.js

Tags: nvd3.js

I use a multiBarChart with nvd3.js
The value of the y is a number with four or two digits - I need them for the mouseover effect on the bars. But I don't want to show the max y as a number with four digits.

How can I format only the y-max or y-min?

Here my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axman/w6rx2h1k/4/

Here how I format the y-Axis

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('N2'));
```

Thx.

Comment: Do you want to set a precision of 2 decimal places for y axis values?

Comment: @ovvn: I certainly don't want any decimals.

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve by this line `chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('N2'));`?

Comment: You can find a documentation for d3.format at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting

Comment: Sorry, the N2 was a copy-past mistake.
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('f')); did the trick.